# Cant understand the read stream's encoding?

Tags: unicode, encoding, serial-port, ascii, utf

I have a c# code:

```
while (true) {

                String s = portR.ReadLine();
                byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(s);
                File.WriteAllBytes("byte.txt", byteArray);
                Console.WriteLine(s);
            }
```

it reads from a serial port where a simulator/machine is sending data in certain encoded form( unknown to me). When I read the data it is not ASCII format in console or the file where i saved.

Its like:

> ??,y?    ??????`??H@???5??? ??   ???I0???????(? ??????@?????/??/???????*??????5    ??????]?

What to do? I want to read it in ASCII format. please help

Comment: most likely the data just isn't in ASCII. open the file in the HEX editor of your choice, to hopefully get a clue about what their format is and then convert it in your code accordingly.

Comment: Read the sender's documentation. Encodings are an agreement that must be communicated.

Comment: Are you sure it isn't a baud rate issue?  When baud rates don't match between both devices you often see garbage like this.

Comment: Try using `Encoding.GetEncoding(28591)` instead of `Encoding.ASCII`. That should be able to handle characters 0x00  - 0xFF without losing data. Chances are that `portR.ReadLine()` is reading raw 8bit bytes and extending them to 16bit string characters as-is instead of actually converting them to Unicode (but check the documentation of `ReadLine()` to make sure).

Comment: If you don't actually know the sender's format, you are just guessing, and are likely to get things wrong at times. You showed what you are ending up with, but what is the sender actually sending? Have you tried reading and saving the data as raw bytes instead of as strings?